# Fire callback after async Task method

Tags: c#, async-await

I need to fire a callback when the `foreach` loop has finished searching through each item int the `List<>`.

```
private async void startSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Search(files, selectTxcDirectory.SelectedPath, status);
}

private static async Task Search(List<string> files, string path, Label statusText)
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(file);

        statusText.Text = "Started scanning...";
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml), new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "LineName"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Why not pass a delegate as parameter and invoke it in `foreach` loop where you need to? Am I missing something?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.asynccallback.aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You are not missing anything, it's because I don't know what passing a delegate as a param and invoking it in the foreach loop is 8-) Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is very simple, just pass a method as a delegate in parameter. then invoke it wherever you need.

```
private async void startSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Search(files, selectTxcDirectory.SelectedPath, status, SearchCompleted); // <-- pass the callback method here
}

private static async Task Search(List<string> files, string path, Label statusText, Action<string> callback)
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(file);

        statusText.Text = "Started scanning...";
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml), new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "LineName"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                }
            }
        }

        // Here you're done with the file so invoke the callback that's it.
        callback(file); // pass which file is finished
    }
}

private static void SearchCompleted(string file)
{
    // This method will be called whenever a file is processed.
}
```

Comment: plain and simple, helped me a lot

Comment: How to handle if  the `SearchCompleted` would be async method?

Answer (score 4):

I'd code it like below. This way, you still keep track of the pending task (`_pendingSearch`), while `startSearchBtn_Click` remains synchronous.

You should be keeping track of pending tasks (and be able to cancel them). Otherwise, user may click `startSearchBtn` twice in a row and spawn two search tasks. This still may be a valid scenario in your case, but usually it is not.

```
Task _pendingSearch = null;
private void startSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if is _pendingSearch != null and still pending here

    _pendingSearch = Search(files, 
        selectTxcDirectory.SelectedPath, status).ContinueWith((finishedTask) => 
    {
        // Place your completion callback code here
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
}

private static async Task Search(List<string> files, string path, Label statusText)
{
    // ...
}
```

**[EDITED]** Using `await`:

```
Task _pendingSearch = null;
private async void startSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if is _pendingSearch != null and still pending here

    _pendingSearch = Search(files, selectTxcDirectory.SelectedPath, status);
    await _pendingSearch;
    // Place your completion callback code here
}
```

Comment: How is this better than using `await`?

Comment: @svick, my point is to not use fire-and-forget approach, when user may click this button multiple times. My personal preference is to not have `async void` event handlers specifically to avoid fire-and-forget. Nevertheless, it's possible to keep track of the pending task inside `async void` method, I've updated the code to show that.

Comment: Except the two pieces of code do something different. In your `ContinueWith()` sample, `_pendingSearch` represents the continuation. In the `await` sample, it's the `Search()` `Task`.

Comment: True, as I just can't wrap `startSearchBtn_Click` itself as `Task`. That's another reason I still like the `ContinueWith` approach. If it implemented the cancellation pattern and passed a token to `ContinueWith`, that'd effectively cancel the callback code too. Of course, the `await` version can (and should) handle this case with `try/catch`.

Comment: You can have all of that code in a `Task`, you would just need a separate `async Task` method (or maybe an `async Task` lambda).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `await`, your code in `startSearchBtn_Click` won't continue until `Search` is finished.

All you need is something like this:

```
private async void startSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Search(files, selectTxcDirectory.SelectedPath, status);
    // run your callback here
}
```

Comment: Yes "callback" has no meaning in this use case